# Bootstrap 5.3 scrollspy weird behaviour on click of the items

Tags: scroll

I'm building a small FAQ section for my website. All with Bootstrap. The items are simple text links. When scrolling, the correct area is highlighted accordingly.

But as soon as I click on it, another (wrong) area becomes active.
What could that be?

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div id="faqlist" class="d-flex flex-column gap-2 simple-list-example-scrollspy">
       <a class="text-start faqlink" href="#item1">Item 1</a>
       <a class="text-start faqlink" href="#item2">Item 2</a>
       <a class="text-start faqlink" href="#item3">Item 3</a>
       <a class="text-start faqlink" href="#item4">Item 4</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">

  <div data-bs-spy="scroll" 
  data-bs-target="#faqlist" 
  data-bs-smooth-scroll="true"
  data-bs-offset="0"
  class="scrollspy-example" tabindex="0">

<h4 id="item1">Header Item 1</h4>
<p>Bla Bla Item 1</p>

<h4 id="item2">Header Item 2</h4>
<p>Bla Bla Item 2</p>

<h4 id="item3">Header Item 3</h4>
<p>Bla Bla Item 3</p>

<h4 id="item4">Header Item 4</h4>
<p>Bla Bla Item 4</p>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>

CSS:
.scrollspy-example {
 position: relative;
 height: 800px;
 overflow: auto;
 padding-right: 2em;
}
```